# Conference presenting: stick to initial paper submission or include recent improvements?

Tags: publications, conference, presentation

I submitted a paper for a conference. While the paper got submitted for publication in the proceedings, the feedback seemed quite negative. The main criticism was that the model I have designed uses too many simplifications.

I am giving a presentation at the conference in about a week and a half. Since I submitted the original paper I have achieved a significant amount, and have been able to improve my model and deal with a number of the simplifications.

My question is: for the presentation content, do I have to stick with the work that is going to be published, or can I also present some of the more interesting, newer work?

For reference, my field is engineering (renewable energy)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> do I have to stick with the work that is going to be published, or can I also present some of the more interesting, newer work?

Absolutely present the improved model.

Conference submissions photograph the state of the work at the time of the submission. But from the submission deadline to the conference, many months can pass and usually people continue to work on their projects. Frequently, by the time of the conference, new results have been obtained, and these surely deserve to be presented.

Comment: In fact, some conferences explicitly state that they encourage speakers to present new developments and results that were obtained after their abstract/paper was submitted.

Comment: and if you didn't it's possible a lot of feedback would be about doing... what you've already done and thus would not be helpful or constructive.  Comments on the improved model will be more valuable and might otherwise be missed if the focus is the (resolved) issues.

Comment: Nonetheless, the OP should mention that what he is presenting is an improved version compared to the proceedings, otherwise people actually reading the proceedings version (the most interested people) might get lost.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the conference and how strict the rules are. My approach would be to use a quarter of the poster space to describe how you have made progress on the model, and how you are planning to further improve it. The rest would describe the model you have submitted.

Comment: I find it very odd to assume that the OP is presenting a poster since no mention was made of this.